# Using MudBlazor in a Razor Class Library

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, blazor

I want to create a personal razor class library inside which I need to use MudBlazor. How can I achieve this without requiring the user to install MudBlazor on their project?
The issue is that MudBlazor gets added to the Razor class, but I cannot configure its JavaScript and CSS in the project. I also don't want the user to have to configure MudBlazor in their project. Is there a way for me to handle the settings within the Razor class project so that the user only needs to use my Razor class?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're going to find a "clean" way to handle this. At a minimum your library will have to implement an `AddMyLibrary()` method to be called on the IServiceCollection in the composition root. And inside that method you would attach MudBlazor to the collection on behalf of the user. Much in the same way that when you call `AddMudBlazor()` that method is doing more than just adding one thing to the collection.

The real problem is that MudBlazor requires additional setup inside the application in order to function properly. Lines need to be added to the MainLayout so that the supporting components MudBlazor uses for a good bit of functionality are available. Maybe if you aren't using the SnackBar or Popover systems you don't need those, but then you risk running into the bigger problem...

What happens if someone wants to use MudBlazor in general *and* your library? How do you expect the user to reconcile the configuration methods used by both systems? It's adding a layer of confusion that I personally find unnecessary.

The proper way for these kinds of systems to be used is to set them up as if they were independent. When we have a class library project that handles our data access with EF Core that gets used in a frontend project like Blazor we have to configure the DbContext in the Blazor project. I'm sure some people would rather abstract that away completely, but having the maintainer of the frontend project define how they want the DbContext to get configured and created is best practice.

It's also best practice that your class library use MudBlazor as a Nuget package, and if you make your library available to others you do so as a Nuget package. That way the users of your library can update MudBlazor independently of your code as fixes get released. You can limit the version number range that your package is compatible with to help prevent breaking changes, but if you are completely hiding away the MudBlazor implementation you're using you are effectively locking the user into whatever specific version you deployed with.

So the short answer is: Don't take away your user's ability to manage their dependencies and composition root under the guise of trying to make things easier for them. You're only hurting them in the long run.